# Iboutlet connected yet Still says it's null

Tags: iphone, iboutlet

I'm new at iPhone development and was practicing a bit.  I connected a uilabel I made through IB to an IBOutlet in my code as many tutorials said but upon trying to set text of it it's still saying it's null?  I defined the IBOutlet object on my .h class and connected it fine through IB without a problem but idk why it's still null.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the class instantiated?  In particular, are you sure it's via a NIB load?

Comment: It's the standard view application template, im just trying to make a basic calculator to practice. my nib file is added as a subview in the app delegate

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first things first, let's remove some of the extraneous stuff and focus on the core of what you need.

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController 
{
    CalculatorBrain* _calculatorModel;
    UILabel *display;
}

- (IBAction) digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *display;

@end


#import "CalculatorViewController.h"

@implementation CalculatorViewController
@synthesize display;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [display release], display = nil;
    [_calculatorModel release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (! _calculatorModel)
    {
        _calculatorModel = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"display is: %@", display);
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *currentDigit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentDigit]];
}

@end
```

Let us know what happens when you've set the label (display) and the action (digitPressed:) in InterfaceBuilder.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your property to copy (or retain, but copy is more idiomatic for this situation):

`@property (copy) IBOutlet UILabel *display;`

Your `assign` property is not incrementing the reference count for the string, thus there is no guarantee that it will still exist by the time you need it.

Comment: No. Copy should only be used when you don't want something changing underneath you, such as an NSMutableArray or an NSString. Additionally, there is some debate between using `retain` vs. `assign` with nib files.